# Angular time range

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

how can I get the value of the below row in a column in Angular?
I'm planning to set the maxDate = upper row of the current row and minDate = below row of the current row.

Example

Here's my HTML code.

```
<div class="time-range-example">
    <input[ngxTimepicker]="range" [min]="minDate" max="maxDate" readonly>
    <ngx-material-timepicker #range></ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```